# CSS on:hover changing childs attributes

Tags: css, html, hover, parent-child

so i was wondering if this where possible.

i am building a navigation.

```
<nav id="navigation">
  <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="/">home</a></div>
  <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="/system/">system</a></div>
  <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="/studies/">studies</a></div>
  <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="/approach/">approach</a></div>
  <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="/about/">about</a></div>
  <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="/contact/">contact</a></div>
</nav>
```

but what i would like is so that when i hover over one of them both the border of the div and the color of the < a > tags text change at the same time

i tried this

```
   #navigation {
     text-align: center;
     height: 150px;
     padding-top: 100px;

    }
  .nav_buttons {    
    display: inline; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
  #navigation a{
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    }


  div.nav_buttons:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff3300;

  }
  div.nav_buttons:hover a{
    color:#ff3300;
  }
```

but that only changed the boder. i am willing to use javascript but i saw that you can change a child element buy hover overing the parent.

```
div#parent_element:hover div.chil_element {color: red;}
```

any suggestions doing it simply in CSS would be epic??

Comment: The color of the anchor tag changes for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jUSZ8/

Comment: That should work. Do you define any general styles for `a` elements?

Comment: @TheLegend:[See This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14476207/1516616)

Comment: FINALLY GOT IT!!! hahahaahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends for a matter of (previous) rule specificity, since you assigned the style with `#navigation a` selector. So try this

```
#navigation > div:hover a {
    color:#ff3300;
}
```

or try simply with `!important`

```
div.nav_buttons:hover a {
    color:#ff3300 !important;
}
```

---

As a side note: you could also avoid to use a repeated class name for every div in the markup and use instead `#navigation > div` to refer those elements

Comment: Agree but it's worth to mention it.

Comment: i just tried it and still nothing the div-border changes but the text remains the same. thanks for the #navigation > div tip

Comment: @TheLegend unless you have other style elsewhere `#navigation > div:hover a` must work since it has an higher specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. But I think some existing styles are overriding your current style. So I suggest to use relative styling technique like below to achieve the desired result:

```
  #navigation div.nav_buttons:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff3300;

  }

  #navigation div.nav_buttons:hover a{
    color:#ff3300;
  }
```

See a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/Bqeav/)

Comment: i misspelt important! lol. troubleshooting 101: 1. spelling error.